# How to have different compile time implementations based on generics

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a builder and would like to guide the users the required input based on specific types, an example of something I'm trying to achieve would be:

```
AddLog<Person>(new Info{Name = "john", LastName = "doe"})
vs
AddLog<Company>(new Info{Name = "company", ParentOrg = "parent company"})
```

Where in the 2 separate examples Info class is a different implementation

```
public class Info {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}
vs
public class Info {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string ParentOrg {get;set;}
}
```

Is there something like this possible, or without using generics?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is this `Info` class? Personally for me the question is not clear.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to have multiple `AddLog` methods that take different `Info` class as a parameter based on their generic parameter and have a different logic, aka template method specialization. I am afraid that this is not possible in C#. I would suggest either using concrete methods (`AddPersonLog`, `AddCompanyLog`), or create distinct types `PersonInfo` and `CompanyInfo` that implement the same interface based on whatever the different `AddLog` specializations meant to do.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek - exact

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - Info be more like 'Log' class I guess, and I'm trying to avoid creating distinct AddLog methods and Info classes